# Get detailed breakdown of memory consumption for Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-appsearch

For ElasticSearch (provisioned through AppSearch), is there a way to get a detailed breakdown of consumed memory within the jvm or elastic process?

We are currently suffering from a lot of circuit breaks but there is no obvious cache or index that seems to be consuming a large amount of memory.

The `request_cache`, `query_cache`, and `fielddata` index are all relatively small.

When we use the `_cache/clear` endpoint, we get a brief respite, but its not permanent

Edit: Example of one of our circuit breaker errors

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "circuit_breaking_exception",
                "reason": "[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [15357980864/14.3gb], which is larger than the limit of [15125499084/14gb], real usage: [15357970248/14.3gb], new bytes reserved: [10616/10.3kb], usages [model_inference=0/0b, inflight_requests=10616/10.3kb, request=0/0b, fielddata=77884/76kb, eql_sequence=0/0b]",
                "bytes_wanted": 15357980864,
                "bytes_limit": 15125499084,
                "durability": "PERMANENT"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack monitoring has a graph tracking memory usage of a node. But what’s your query and size of data targeted ?

Comment: Thanks. I see the 3 graphs on the advanced tab, labeled: JVM Heap (GB), Index Memory - Elasticsearch (MB) and Index Memory - Lucene. The first is the highest and the problem by the looks of things, ill dig into this. The other two are inconsiquential. My query returns about 50 fields, and has 20 disjunctive aggregations, with a couple of post and pre filters, and a query term. We have one data index sitting at about 7GB with about 100k documents

Comment: Check GC activity. If you have a lot of them at query time, it can be memory requirements of your query that is too high. Coordinator only node could help.

By the way, please copy paste the circuit breaker exception. It has some important info.